# Using php mysql set auto_increment primary value into other field

Tags: php, mysql

how can i set id primarykey auto_increment same value that automatically generating into my id field will also generate in other field in same table.

How could it possible?

Comment: see this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin

Comment: Hi Danish..
Could it possible to copy one field value into other field automatically?

Comment: yeah. What you do is.. first write insert query command. Ok.. find the Auto-incremented id through $LastID=mysql_insert_id();. Now you can use this $LastID to update the column you want. for ex: UPDATE tablename SET columnname='$LastID' WHERE ID='$LastID'. 

But, first Insert query, then mysql_insert_id(), then update query ok. Try it.

Comment: Yes Danish I understood thanks a lot

Comment: Say thanks to @unniBabu.. he also thought same.

Comment: Yeah sure you also deserve you both are frnds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **mysql_insert_id** which returns last auto increment ID...

1) insert into first table, use mysql_insert_id() to get auto increment ID
2) after getting auto increment ID from 1st table, insert on second table with the ID you got.

for more refer http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Wow, I read `mysql_insert_id`, anyone else who wants to post an answer and still uses the deprecated mysql_* functions?